# Problems with contenttypes when loading a fixture in Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, fixtures, mysql-error-1062

I am having trouble loading Django fixtures into my MySQL database because of contenttypes conflicts. First I tried dumping the data from only my app like this:

```
./manage.py dumpdata escola > fixture.json
```

but I kept getting missing foreign key problems, because my app "escola" uses tables from other applications. I kept adding additional apps until I got to this:

```
./manage.py dumpdata contenttypes auth escola > fixture.json
```

Now the problem is the following constraint violation when I try to load the data as a test fixture:

```
IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'escola-t23aluno' for key 2")
```

It seems the problem is that Django is trying to dynamically recreate contenttypes with different primary key values that conflict with the primary key values from the fixture. This appears to be the same as bug documented here: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7052

The problem is that the recommended workaround is to dump the contenttypes app which I'm already doing!? What gives? If it makes any difference I do have some custom model permissions as documented here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#permissions

Answer (score 170):

`manage.py dumpdata --natural` will use a more durable representation of foreign keys. In django they are called "natural keys". For example:

- `Permission.codename` is used in favour of `Permission.id`
- `User.username` is used in favour of `User.id`

Read more: [natural keys section in "serializing django objects"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys)

Some other useful arguments for `dumpdata`:

- `--indent=4` make it human readable.
- `-e sessions` exclude session data
- `-e admin` exclude history of admin actions on admin site
- `-e contenttypes -e auth.Permission` exclude objects which are recreated automatically from schema every time during `syncdb`. Only use it together with `--natural` or else you might end up with badly aligned id numbers.

Comment: I am using this to get natural keys for a content_type attribute, but I get this error when trying to load back the fixtures. TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
  Any idea why ?

Comment: @skyjur Why always use `-e contenttypes -e auth.permission` with `--natural`? I just tried without the `--natural` option and it worked. Also the [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---natural) says one should use this option if **DUMPING** `auth.permission` and `contenttypes`.

Comment: @winirvana because after you start from scratch and do syncdb, newly created `ContentType` and `Permission` are not guaranteed to get same id as they had before. Your data dump contains ids which might reference different objects on anather database where you will loaddata. It might worked for you because of one of these reasons: 1) your data didn't had any reference to these objects 2) original ids of Permission/ContentTypes were preserved 3) your loaddata was succesful but you actually have corrupt data due to objects referring to wrong objects and you don't yet know about it

Comment: Flag `--natural` is now deprecated in favor of `--natural-foreign` (and `--natural-primary`)

Comment: Final command could be: `manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission --indent 4 > project_dump.json`

Comment: `--natural` has now been completely removed, not just deprecated. Use `--natural-foreign` or `--natural-primary` instead.

Answer (score 50):

The answers here all old...  As of 2017, the best answer is:

```
manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission --indent 4
```

Answer (score 36):

Yes, this is really irritating.  For a while I worked around it by doing a "manage.py reset" on the contenttypes app prior to loading the fixture (to get rid of the automatically-generated contenttypes data that differed from the dumped version).  That worked, but eventually I got sick of the hassles and abandoned fixtures entirely in favor of straight SQL dumps (of course, then you lose DB portability).

**update** - the best answer is to use the `--natural` flag to `dumpdata`, as noted in an answer below. That flag did not exist yet when I wrote this answer.

Comment: I was running into this too, resetting the contenttypes app worked for me as well. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: How did you reset them? In test case class? Give me an example please

Comment: I don't use fixtures for unittests, I generally create test data using the ORM in a setup() method because it's easier to keep in sync with the tests. So I never had to do this in a TestCase class, though I'm sure if you poke around in the code for Django's TestCase class you could figure out how to make a reset happen post syncdb and prior to fixture loading in a subclass. For me it was just "./manage.py reset contenttypes" in a bash script prior to "./manage.py loaddata my_fixture".

Answer (score 35):

Try skipping contenttypes when creating fixture:

```
./manage.py dumpdata --exclude contenttypes > fixture.json
```

It worked for me in a similar situation for unit tests, your insight regarding the contenttypes really helped!

Answer (score 17):

I was not using MySQL but instead importing some data from a live server into sqlite. Clearing the `contenttypes` app data before performing `loaddata` did the trick:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
ContentType.objects.all().delete()
quit()
```

And then

```
python manage.py loaddata data.json
```

Comment: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: It would probably work best within the handle of a custom management command.

Answer (score 10):

I have resolved this issue in my test cases by resetting the contenttypes app from the unit test prior to loading my dump file. Carl suggested this already using the `manage.py` command and I do the same thing only using the `call_command` method:

```
>>> from django.core import management
>>> management.call_command("flush", verbosity=0, interactive=False)
>>> management.call_command("reset", "contenttypes", verbosity=0, interactive=False)
>>> management.call_command("loaddata", "full_test_data.json", verbosity=0)
```

My `full_test_data.json` fixture contains the contenttypes app dump that corresponds to the rest of the test data. By resetting the app before loading, it prevents the duplicate key `IntegrityError`.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use natural keys to represent any foreign key and many-to-many relationships. Moreover, it might be a good idea to exclude the `session` table in the `sessions` app, and the `logentry` table in the `admin` app.

**Django 1.7+**

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --exclude contenttypes --exclude auth.permission --exclude admin.logentry --exclude sessions.session --indent 4 > fixture.json
```

**Django <1.7**

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural --exclude contenttypes --exclude auth.permission --exclude admin.logentry --exclude sessions.session --indent 4 > fixture.json
```

According to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/), `--natural` has been deprecated in version 1.7, so the option `--natural-foreign` should be used instead.

You can also omit the primary key in the serialized data of this object since it can be calculated during deserialization by passing the `--natural-primary` flag.

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary --exclude contenttypes --exclude auth.permission --exclude admin.logentry --exclude sessions.session --indent 4 > fixture.json
```

Answer (score 7):

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural-primary --exclude=contenttypes --exclude=auth.Permission --exclude=admin.logentry --exclude=sessions.session --indent 4 > initial_data.json
```

This works for me. Here I am excluding everything bubt the actual models.

- If you see any other model other than the models that you created you can safely exclude those. One drawback of this approach is you loose on log data as well as auth data.

Answer (score 4):

```
./manage.py dumpdata app.Model --natural-foreign
```

will change

```
  "content_type": 123
```

to

```
  "content_type": [
    "app_label",
    "model"
  ],
```

And fixture works for `TestCase` now

Answer (score 3):

**Django 2.2.5**

```
python manage.py dumpdata --exclude=contenttypes > datadump.json
```

it helped me

Comment: It will raise problem when loaddata, maybe mismatch with contenttype in new database

Answer (score 2):

It's really, really annoying .. I get bitten by this every single time.

I tried to dumpdata with --exclude contenttypes and --natural, I always get problems..

What works best for me is simply doing a `truncate table django_content_type;` after the syncdb and THEN load the data.

Of course for initial_data.json autoloading you're fallball.

Comment: For me, truncating the table prior to loaddata just causes different errors. No luck with this technique.

Answer (score 2):

I tried every method from above, Nothing worked for me. I have to exclude the complete auth model and works fine.

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural-primary --exclude=contenttypes --exclude=auth --exclude=admin.logentry --exclude=sessions.session --indent 4 > live.json
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give another possible answer that I just figured out. Maybe it'll help the OP, maybe it'll help somebody else.

I've got a many-to-many relationship table. It has a primary key and the two foreign keys to the other tables. I found that if I have an entry in the fixture whose two foreign keys are the same as another entry already in the table with a *different* pk, it will fail. M2M relationship tables have a "unique together" for the two foreign keys.

So, if it's a M2M relationship that is breaking, look at the foreign keys it's adding, look at your database to see if that pair of FKs are already listed under a different PK.

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered similar error sometimes ago. It turned out that I was trying to load the fixtures before creating the necessary tables. So I did:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
$ python manage.py loaddata fixtures/initial_data.json
```

And it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had dumped the data from `auth` (`./manage.py dumpddata auth > fixtures/auth.json`) to use the fixture for testing purposes.

The development continued and I removed most of the models I had defined in `models.py` and this is when I started to see this annoying problem.

My solution was regenerating the auth.json fixture again. This one had removed lots of entries in `auth.permission` related to the old models I had.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by adding in my tests setUp and tearDown

```
from django.core import management
```

=====

```
def setUp(self):
    management.call_command("loaddata", "all-data.yaml", verbosity=0)
    super(login_page_test, self).setUp()

def tearDown(self):
    management.call_command("flush", verbosity=0, interactive=False)
    super(login_page_test, self).setUp()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [pgloader](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/sqlite.html#sqlite-to-postgres), just take a few seconds to migrate successfully:

```
$ pgloader project.load
```

project.load file with:

```
load database
     from sqlite:////path/to/dev.db
     into postgresql://user:pwd@localhost/db_name

 with include drop, create tables, create indexes, reset sequences

   set work_mem to '16MB', maintenance_work_mem to '512 MB';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to exclude some types of data in the database when dumping data.

First, dump data:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --indent 4 > datadump.json
```

A few lines from this file for example:

> [
>
> {
> **"model": "admin.logentry"**,
> "pk": 1,
> "fields": {
> "action_time": "2023-09-28T08:33:24.827Z",
> "user": 1,
> "content_type": 3,
> "object_id": "1",
> "object_repr": "user",
> "action_flag": 1,
> "change_message": "[{"added": {}}]"
> } },
>
> ...
>
> {
> **"model": "auth.permission"**,
> "pk": 1,
> "fields": {
> "name": "Can add log entry",
> "content_type": 1,
> "codename": "add_logentry"
> } },
>
> ...
>
> {
> **"model": "auth.group"**,
> "pk": 1,
> "fields": {
> "name": "user",
> "permissions": [
> 25,
> 26,
> 27
> ]
> } },
>
> ...
>
> ]

Try to search and see the text like this `"model"` in the json dump file.

You can also find all types of content in the `contenttype` model, a table for the this model is `django_content_type`:

```
SELECT * FROM django_content_type ORDER BY id;
```

An example of data from this table:

```
+----+--------------+----------------+
| id | app_label    | model          |
+----+--------------+----------------+
|  1 | admin        | logentry       |
|  2 | auth         | permission     |
|  3 | auth         | group          |
|  4 | contenttypes | contenttype    |
|  5 | sessions     | session        |
|  6 | user         | user           |
|  7 | user         | historicaluser |
|  8 | constance    | constance      |
|  9 | tracking     | pageview       |
| 10 | tracking     | visitor        |
+----+--------------+----------------+
```

After you can exclude this type of data by adding several `--exclude` to the `manage.py dumpdata`

For example:

- "model": "auth.permission", can be excluded like this: `--exclude auth.permission`. Using this option `--exclude auth` you can exclude all models for application `auth`, if there are such models, in this case these will be the `permission` and the `group` models.
- "model": "contenttypes.contenttype", can be excluded like this: `--exclude contenttypes.contenttype`.
- "model": "user.historicaluser", can be excluded like this: `--exclude user.historicaluser`.
- "model": "sessions.session", can be excluded like this: `--exclude sessions.session` or `--exclude sessions`.
- "model": "tracking.pageview", can be excluded like this: `--exclude tracking.pageview`. If you use `--exclude tracking`, both models `tracking.pageview` and `tracking.visitor` will be excluded.

The final code for 5 lines above:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes --exclude user.historicaluser --exclude sessions.session --exclude tracking --indent 4 > dumpdata.json
```

You can also combine the dump script with `--natural-foreign` and `--natural-primary` options, read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/serialization/#natural-keys.