# django fixtures: Where to add a fixture file

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, fixtures

I am trying to create a set of test case to cover my django application. I need pre defined database data, to run some of my test. So I decided to use fixtures.

What I did was:
1) created fixture file: 
   oleg$ python manage.py dumpdata goserver > fixture1.json
2) Placed the fixture in the directory where application lives
   oleg$ cp fixture1.json goserver/
3) Write down the texture name in the tests file in my application

```
   class GoserverTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['fixture1.json']

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def testUserIsAdded(self):
        print "Users" , User.objects.all()
        #print ActiveList.objects.all()
        self.assertEquals(True, True)
```

4) Run the text case with a command: 
oleg$ python manage.py test --verbosity=2 goserver

The output of the test run is (part of it):

> Trying '/Users/oleg/jin/goclub/trunk/jin/../jin/register/fixtures'
>   for xml fixture 'initial_data'... No
>   xml fixture 'initial_data' in
>   '/Users/oleg/jin/goclub/trunk/jin/../jin/register/fixtures'.
>   Trying
>   '/Users/oleg/jin/goclub/trunk/jin/../jin/register/fixtures'
>   for json fixture 'initial_data'... No
>   json fixture 'initial_data' in
>   '/Users/oleg/jin/goclub/trunk/jin/../jin/register/fixtures'.
>   Checking
>   '/Users/oleg/jin/goclub/trunk/jin/../jin/captcha/fixtures'
>   for fixtures... Trying
>   '/Users/oleg/jin/goclub/trunk/jin/../jin/captcha/fixtures'
>   for xml fixture 'initial_data'... No
>   xml fixture 'initial_data' in
>   '/Users/oleg/jin/goclub/trunk/jin/../jin/captcha/fixtures'.
>   Trying
>   '/Users/oleg/jin/goclub/trunk/jin/../jin/captcha/fixtures'
>   for json fixture 'initial_data'... No
>   json fixture 'initial_data' in
>   '/Users/oleg/jin/goclub/trunk/jin/../jin/captcha/fixtures'.
>   Checking
>   '/Users/oleg/jin/goclub/trunk/jin/../jin/goserver/fixtures'
>   for fixtures... Trying
>   '/Users/oleg/jin/goclub/trunk/jin/../jin/goserver/fixtures'
>   for xml fixture 'initial_data'... No
>   xml fixture 'initial_data' in
>   '/Users/oleg/jin/goclub/trunk/jin/../jin/goserver/fixtures'.
>   Trying
>   '/Users/oleg/jin/goclub/trunk/jin/../jin/goserver/fixtures'
>   for json fixture 'initial_data'... No
>   json fixture 'initial_data' in
>   '/Users/oleg/jin/goclub/trunk/jin/../jin/goserver/fixtures'.
>   Checking '/' for fixtures... Trying
>   '/' for xml fixture 'initial_data'...
>   No xml fixture 'initial_data' in '/'.
>   Trying '/' for json fixture
>   'initial_data'... No json fixture
>   'initial_data' in '/'. Checking 'U'
>   for fixtures... Trying 'U' for xml
>   fixture 'initial_data'... No xml
>   fixture 'initial_data' in 'U'. Trying
>   'U' for json fixture 'initial_data'...
>   No json fixture 'initial_data' in 'U'.
>   Checking 's' for fixtures... Trying
>   's' for xml fixture 'initial_data'...
>   No xml fixture 'initial_data' in 's'.
>   Trying 's' for json fixture
>   'initial_data'..

Actually the problem is that the fixture was not found at all, so no data I wanted to add into the test database was added. Could you please suggest me a way to solve the problem

I tried a new way to do it. 
I just made a dump of complete database and put it to the application folder.

But I came cross some encoding issues.

Can you please check the error response:

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 168, in execute
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-i386/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 82, in _warning_check
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/warnings.py", line 62, in warn
    globals)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/warnings.py", line 102, in warn_explicit
    raise message
Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x9D\xD0\xB0 \xD0...' for column 'object_repr' at row 1

testUserIsAdded (jin.goserver.tests.GoserverTestCase) ... Users []

### Have another problem. When I disabled fixtures I still getting an error:

### Unit Test Code Coverage Results

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in 
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.0.2_final-py2.5.egg/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 340, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.0.2_final-py2.5.egg/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 295, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.0.2_final-py2.5.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 192, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.**dict**)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.0.2_final-py2.5.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 219, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.0.2_final-py2.5.egg/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 33, in handle
    failures = test_runner(test_labels, verbosity=verbosity, interactive=interactive)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django_test_coverage-0.1-py2.5.egg/django-test-coverage/runner.py", line 58, in run_tests
    modules.extend(_package_modules(*pkg))
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django_test_coverage-0.1-py2.5.egg/django-test-coverage/runner.py", line 92, in _package_modules
    modules.append(**import**(impstr + '.' + name, {}, {}, ['']))
  File "/Users/oleg/jin/goclub/trunk/jin/goserver/admin.py", line 11, in 
    admin.site.register(ActiveList, ActiveListAdmin)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.0.2_final-py2.5.egg/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 64, in register
    raise AlreadyRegistered('The model %s is already registered' % model.**name**)
django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model ActiveList is already registered

Comment: Things became more complicated to me now. I exported the whole database and, now when the fixture is loaded I constantly get
IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'goserver-activelist' for key 'app_label'")

Not sure why the error appears. I tried to refresh database from production (just in case I added the application 2 times in dev somehow), but the error is still the same.

I also trying to less through the fixture file, to see duplicates, but didn't manage to get any of them

Comment: Actually the last part of it is a separate question

Comment: Oleg, have you found solution for "Duplicate entry..." problem?

Comment: Removed content type application from dump

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the first question of where to put a fixture file: Create a folder in each app called fixtures, and place your fixture data there.

To your second problem regarding your integrity errors, check out this discussion of problems with contenttypes and fixtures:

[Problems with contenttypes when loading a fixture in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853796/problems-with-contenttypes-when-loading-a-fixture-in-django)

Comment: Django now also looks into `setting.FIXTURE_DIRS` can be handy to manually point to a locations for apps that you did not create yourself, for example de default user app.