# Switching to PostgreSQL fails loading datadump

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite

Using sqlite3 and Django I want to change to PostgreSQL and keep all data intact. I used `./manage.py dumpdata > dump.json` to dump the data, and changed settings to use PostgreSQL.

With an empty database `./manage.py loaddata dump.json` resulted in errors about tables not existing, so I ran `./manage.py syncdb` and tried again. That results in this error:

```
Problem installing fixture 'dump.json': Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 163, in handle
    obj.save()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 163, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, raw=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 495, in save_base
    rows = manager.filter(pk=pk_val)._update(values)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 448, in _update
    return query.execute_sql(None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 124, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(UpdateQuery, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 2347, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 19, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django_content_type_app_label_key"
```

Is this not the correct way to move data from one database to another? How should I switch database backend safely?

Comment: i ignored some django tables. `./manage.py dumpdata -e sessions -e admin -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission -e authtoken --natural > db.json` and then did `./manage.py loaddata db.json`. Maybe it helps someone. For details see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853796/problems-with-contenttypes-when-loading-a-fixture-in-django

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem is simply that you're getting the content types defined twice - once when you do `syncdb`, and once from the exported data you're trying to import. Since you may well have other items in your database that depend on the original content type definitions, I would recommend keeping those.

So, after running `syncdb`, do `manage.py dbshell` and in your database do `TRUNCATE django_content_type;` to remove all the newly-defined content types. Then you shouldn't get any conflicts - on that part of the process, in any case.

Comment: In my case, postgres complained that it could not perform the truncation due to foreign key constraints, and suggested adding the CASCADE argument, which worked. So: "TRUNCATE django_content_type CASCADE;"

Comment: In my case I had to  `TRUNCATE django_content_type CASCADE;` but it worked great!

Answer (score 2):

There is a big discussion about it on the [Django ticket 7052](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7052). The right way now is to use the `--natural` parameter, example: `./manage.py dumpdata --natural --format=xml --indent=2 > fixture.xml`

In order for `--natural` to work with your models, they must implement `natural_key` and `get_by_natural_key`, as described on [the Django documentation regarding natural keys](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/serialization/).

Having said that, you might still need to edit the data before importing it with `./manage.py loaddata`. For instance, if your applications changed, `syncdb` will populate the table `django_content_type` and you might want to delete the respective entries from the xml-file before loading it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. You probably want to ensure the server is stopped so no new data is lost. Dump it:

```
$ python manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes --natural > db.json
```

Make sure your models don't have signals (e.g. post_save) or anything that creates models. If you do, comment it out momentarily.

Edit settings.py to point to the new database and set it up:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb

$ python manage.py migrate
```

Load the data:

```
./manage.py loaddata db.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I used pgloader, just take a few seconds to migrate successfully:

```
$ pgloader project.load
```

project.load file with:

```
load database
  from sqlite:////path/to/dev.db
  into postgresql://user:pwd@localhost/db_name

with include drop, create tables, create indexes, reset sequences

 set work_mem to '16MB', maintenance_work_mem to '512 MB';
```