# django - loaddata error when converting db from sqlite3 to postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, postgresql-9.1, django-database

I am trying to convert from a sqlite3 db to Postgres (so that I can have timezone-aware datetime fields with django 1.4).  I dumped the data from the sqlite3 db.  Then switched settings to point to the empty postgres db.  Then ran syncdb, then south migrations.  All good so far.

When I try to reload the dumped data into postgres, I get an error:

An exception occurred while loading data: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django_content_type_app_label_model_key" DETAIL: Key (app_label, model)=(django_twilio, caller) already exists.

I removed twilio from the app and still got a similar error, just with the next object in the db.

Any help is appreciated.  I'm new to programming and django.  Thanks!

Comment: Is this a SQL data dump or a Django data dump?

Comment: It is Django. I actually found the answer in an existing stackexchange post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076928/switching-django-project-from-sqlite3-backend-to-postgresql-failes-when-loading.  I needed to TRUNCATE the database.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is Django. I actually found the answer in an existing stackexchange post:

[Switching Django project from sqlite3 backend to postgresql failes when loading datadump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076928/switching-django-project-from-sqlite3-backend-to-postgresql-failes-when-loading)

I needed to TRUNCATE the database. Thank you for your help.