# [django]Error: contenttypes couldn't be reset

Tags: django, reset, loaddata, contenttypes

I reset contenttypes prior to loading the fixture (Refer to [Problems with contenttypes when loading a fixture in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853796/problems-with-contenttypes-when-loading-a-fixture-in-django/855583#855583)).

But contenttypes couldn't be reset:

> ...project_dir > manage.py reset contenttypes
>
> You have requested a database reset. This will IRREVERSIBLY DESTROY
> any data for the "contenttypes" application in the database
> "my_database". Are you sure you want to do this?
>
> Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: **yes**
>
> Error: Error: contenttypes couldn't be reset. Possible reasons:
>
> - The database isn't running or isn't configured correctly.
> - At least one of the database tables doesn't exist.
> - The SQL was invalid.
>
> Hint: Look at the output of 'django-admin.py sqlreset contenttypes'.
> That's the SQL this command wasn't able to run.
>
> The full error: (1217, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a
> foreign key cons traint fails')

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: can you type in the command `django-admin.py sqlreset contenttypes` and see what the error is there?

Comment: Any insight on this? Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

On the question you posted there is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4075921/978434) - use [natural keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys) for fixtures.

The error "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key cons traint fails" means that the content type row can't be deleted as there is another object that points to that row. E.g. if there is any none-blank generic foreign key relation that would be the case.

If you really need to reset the content-type app you can get the SQL command that is needed for this and alter it to use CASCADE statement. However this is **dangerous** as it will delete not only content types but also rows from another tables that points to content-types.

So I advice to re-create fixtures using natural keys.