# Integrity error when loading fixtures for Selenium testing in Django

Tags: django, selenium, fixtures, django-testing

I want to load a fixture for my selenium testing. Using fixtures was successful in my initial tests, so I know I am capable of loading the fixtures in my test setup and using them in my tests. I have attempted several approaches.
First, I generated fixtures specific to the models I was testing using dumpdata. An example is below:

```
python manage.py dumpdata protocols.Step --indent=2 > functional_tests/fixtures/step.json
```

When used in my test as so:

```
class SignInTest(FunctionalTest):
    fixtures = ['admin_user.json', 'protocol.json', 'step.json',
             'protocol_element.json']

    def test_login_and_view_user_data(self):
        ...
```

I get error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixtures: The row in table 'protocols_protocolelement' with primary key '37' has an invalid foreign key: protocols_protocolelement.element_content_type_id contains a value '41' that does not have a corresponding value in django_content_type.id.
```

Second attempt involved using all the test data in my tables, but excluding contenttypes:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --indent=2 -e contenttypes > functional_tests/fixtures/initial_data.json

class SignInTest(FunctionalTest):
    fixtures = ['initial_data.json']
    ...
```

Getting the error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: Problem installing fixture '.../mike/mike/functional_tests/fixtures/initial_data.json': Could not load auth.Permission(pk=103): no such table: auth_permission
```

Next, I tried using natural to show the natural keys:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission --indent=2 > functional_tests/fixtures/initial_data2.json
```

Only to get the error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: Problem installing fixture '.../mike/mike/functional_tests/fixtures/initial_data.json': Could not load auth.User(pk=1): no such table: auth_user
```

Noticing natural was depreciated I tried --natural-foreign and wanted to include user and permission models (I need contenttypes for my models anyway):

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --indent=2 > functional_tests/fixtures/initial_data3.json
```

Only to get the error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '.../mike/mike/functional_tests/fixtures/initial_data3.json': Could not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=35): UNIQUE constraint failed: django_content_type.app_label, django_content_type.model
```

So, any ideas on how to load the fixture so I can run my tests? Is there something simple I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some more reading about how Django maintains its own models and such, it is my understanding that Django caches the contenttype, auth.Permission, etc and uses them in testing frameworks (I was using StaticLiveServerTestCase). This means that when I was loading my fixture, it was clashing with the data Django had stored for its own uses causing the integrity error. This is what worked for me:

```
python manage.py dumpdata -e contenttypes -e admin -e auth.Permission --natural-foreign --indent=2 > functional_tests/fixtures/initial_data4.json
```

This post has some additional helpful information to help me solve the problem:
[Problems with contenttypes when loading a fixture in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853796/problems-with-contenttypes-when-loading-a-fixture-in-django?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

All this exercises around **dumpdata** didn't bring me any result.
But I found this advise:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3855764/12191031
For some reason **reset** doesn't work in my code, but it was enough load fixture before every test and flush DB after each one.
So, my solution is this:

```
from django.core import management
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver

class login_page_test(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    
@classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.selenium = webdriver.Firefox()
        cls.selenium.implicitly_wait(5)
        super(login_page_test, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super(login_page_test, cls).tearDownClass()

    def setUp(self):
        # for every test I load fixture
        management.call_command("loaddata", "user-data.yaml", verbosity=0)
        super(login_page_test, self).setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        # after each test I flush all DB
        management.call_command("flush", verbosity=0, interactive=False)
        super(login_page_test, self).setUp()
```

I'm happy )))