# Convert Full Database to Different database Format using django

Tags: django, database, django-database

I'm switching my database engine and need to convert my data. I can access both databases in a python shell with `.using('[database]')`.  Does django have any built-in backup&restore functions that I could use to fill my empty(but migrated) new database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) to export and [`loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#loaddata) to import.

Here are some examples:

#### dumpdata everything

```
python manage.py dumpdata > all.json
```

#### dumpdata one app

```
python manage.py dumpdata blog > blog.json
```

#### dumpdata specific model of app

```
python manage.py dumpdata blog.articles > blog_articles.json
```

#### loaddata

```
python manage.py loaddata all.json
```

By changing the `settings.py` database connection after you've dumped your data you don't have to use `using` at all.

More on this in the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata).

Comment: thanks, I ran into a few problems importing but found those answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853796/problems-with-contenttypes-when-loading-a-fixture-in-django