# Wagtail moving sqlite to postgres database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, wagtail

**The issue**

I have an empty (migrated) postgres database to which I want to move the data from my sqlite database.

**What I've tried**

- I export with

  ```
  ./manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes --natural-foreign
  ```

  and consequtively load the data into the postgres db with `./manage.py loaddata`.

  The problem here is that wagtail requires the contenttypes and I get a runtime error

  ```
  FooPage matching query does not exist.
  ```

  at

  ```
  /wagtail/wagtailcore/models.py:639 
  return content_type.get_object_for_this_type(id=self.id)
  ```
- Don't exclude `contenttypes` with `dumpdata`. Now the `loaddata` command fails with an `IntegrityError`: `Key ... already exists`.
- I have tried to remove all `ContentType` model objects before loading in the data so that it doesn't whine about duplicate keys. While that works when using the sqlite db, it fails on the postgres db with an `IntegrityError`

  ```
  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "wagtailcore_page".
  ```

**Used versions**

- django 1.11.9
- wagtail 1.12.3
- python 3.5

**Related**

[Problems with contenttypes when loading a fixture in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/q/853796/1627479)

Comment: Try using `--natural-foreign` for `dumpdata`, see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-dumpdata-natural-foreign).

Comment: @rafalmp I've tried that as well, and I've updated the question accordingly

Comment: Too much time is wasted on Djangos dumpdata and loaddata. It is fiddly and hardly ever works.

Answer (score 2):

With [pgloader](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/sqlite.html) you can execute command instructions to load data from SQLite into Postgres.

Install on OSX with Homebrew:

```
brew install pgloader
```

Create a script file. Eg `migrate.script`:

```
load database
     from sqlite:///path/to/db.sqlite3
     into postgresql:///yourpostgresdbname

 with include drop, create tables, create indexes, reset sequences

  set work_mem to '16MB', maintenance_work_mem to '512 MB';
```

Run it:

```
pgloader migrate.script
```

I did a testdrive with a SQLite database containing a minimal Wagtail project (some pages, revisions and images) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This solution worked on Ubuntu / Debian like a breeze. Great solution.

Answer (score 0):

I managed something when I moved my Wagtail site from sqlite to Postgres, so just adding for reference.

I used [this website](https://gist.github.com/sirodoht/f598d14e9644e2d3909629a41e3522ad) as a base, but ran into an error when I couldn't delete ContentType objects right away due to a foreign key issue, as follows:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "wagtailcore_page" violates foreign key constraint "wagtailcore_page_content_type_id_c28424df_fk_django_co"
>
> DETAIL:  Key (content_type_id)=(1) is not present in table "django_content_type".

Seemed like it was due to Wagtail page objects, so executed the following two lines in the Django shell first. Was then able to follow the rest of the instructions on that page, executing the ContentType deletion and the import.

```
from wagtail.core.models import Page
Page.objects.all().delete()
```

Comment: At the moment of loading in my data, there are no existing pages in the database, so this answer does not apply to my question.

Comment: @Joren Sorry it wasn't relevant..Yeah, I didn't think there would be any page data, either, since it was a fresh database and all I had run were the basic migrations. I think the pages were likely wagtail admin pages etc.