# getting error changing database from sqlite to postgreSQL in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have been trying to dump and load data from sqlite to PostgreSQL referring to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853796/problems-with-contenttypes-when-loading-a-fixture-in-django).
However, I got following error when I tried to load data which is dumped by following code.

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission > database.json
```

I tried to dump data removing natural argument as below. But got same error.

```
python manage.py dumpdata -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission > database.json
```

Could anyone tell me what should I do to solve this problem?

```
(webEP) C:\Users\obakatsu\Documents\Python_scripts\Django\DjangoEP>python manage.py loaddata database.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: リレーション"auth_user"は存在しません
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 81, in Deserializer
    for obj in PythonDeserializer(objects, **options):
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\python.py", line 183, in Deserializer
    obj = base.build_instance(Model, data, db)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\base.py", line 227, in build_instance
    obj.pk = Model._default_manager.db_manager(db).get_by_natural_key(*natural_key).pk
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 48, in get_by_natural_key
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 373, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 232, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1102, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 876, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: リレーション"auth_user"は存在しません
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
                                                             ^


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 69, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 109, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 166, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 87, in Deserializer
    six.reraise(DeserializationError, DeserializationError(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 81, in Deserializer
    for obj in PythonDeserializer(objects, **options):
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\python.py", line 183, in Deserializer
    obj = base.build_instance(Model, data, db)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\base.py", line 227, in build_instance
    obj.pk = Model._default_manager.db_manager(db).get_by_natural_key(*natural_key).pk
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 48, in get_by_natural_key
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 373, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 232, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1102, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 876, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\envs\webEP\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture 'C:\Users\obakatsu\Documents\Python_scripts\Django\DjangoEP\database.json': リレーション"auth_user"は存在しません
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
```

Comment: Can you please disable locale language settings or translate the error message to english? Thanks

Comment: Google Translate: Relation "auth _ user" does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

From [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%E3%83%AA%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%22auth_user%22%E3%81%AF%E5%AD%98%E5%9C%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93) the error message is:

> Relation "auth _ user" does not exist

So it seems that you are querying an entity (table, view, function, ...) that just not exist at this moment. Maybe you have to create a table `auth_user` before you execute your code or maybe the whole database schema?

Answer (score 0):

this same happen to me , first take a backup for your database in .json file and the change the settings.py to your desired datatbase and then run commands

```
python manage.py migrate
```

this gradually works for me ! so try once .

Answer (score 0):

python manage.py migrate would help if
you didn't do it after changing database.

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?